# What is the damage of Call Lightning + Maximize Spell?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, druid, metamagic

If you use the Maximize Spell metamagic feat to a Druid's Call lightning, is the damage 18 per bolt (max(3d6)), 30 per bolt (max(3d10)) or does it depend on if there are clouds?

The way I read "All variable, numeric effects of a spell modified by this feat are maximised" in the description of Maximize Spell I think it should be 30 per bolt no matter if there are clouds or not. Reason: The spell damage without maximize spell varies depending on the weather, which can then be counted as a "variable numeric effect". Is that correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sadly, no. "Variable" does not mean "conditional". Variable means that you have a range of values for your spell effect. In this case, based upon the current conditions, your variable is 3d6 and you would max that out at 18. But if it's overcast and cloudy, then your variable would be 3d10 and you would max that out at 30.

Comment: Sad, but I kind of expected that answer ;) Thanks.